# How to display images in p-gallery in case when are File or base64?

Tags: angular, image, primeng, galleria

It is possible? Documentation shows only case for paths of images 
html:

```
<p-galleria [images]="images" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" [showCaption]="true"></p-galleria>
```

ts

```
images: any[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.images = [];
        this.images.push({source:'assets/showcase/images/demo/galleria/galleria1.jpg', alt:'Description for Image 1', title:'Title 1'});
        this.images.push({source:'assets/showcase/images/demo/galleria/galleria2.jpg', alt:'Description for Image 2', title:'Title 2'});
        this.images.push({source:'assets/showcase/images/demo/galleria/galleria3.jpg', alt:'Description for Image 3', title:'Title 3'});
        this.images.push({source:'assets/showcase/images/demo/galleria/galleria4.jpg', alt:'Description for Image 4', title:'Title 4'});
        this.images.push({source:'assets/showcase/images/demo/galleria/galleria5.jpg', alt:'Description for Image 5', title:'Title 5'});
        this.images.push({source:'assets/showcase/images/demo/galleria/galleria6.jpg', alt:'Description for Image 6', title:'Title 6'});
        this.images.push({source:'assets/showcase/images/demo/galleria/galleria7.jpg', alt:'Description for Image 7', title:'Title 7'});
        this.images.push({source:'assets/showcase/images/demo/galleria/galleria8.jpg', alt:'Description for Image 8', title:'Title 8'});
        this.images.push({source:'assets/showcase/images/demo/galleria/galleria9.jpg', alt:'Description for Image 9', title:'Title 9'});
        this.images.push({source:'assets/showcase/images/demo/galleria/galleria10.jpg', alt:'Description for Image 10', title:'Title 10'});
        this.images.push({source:'assets/showcase/images/demo/galleria/galleria11.jpg', alt:'Description for Image 11', title:'Title 11'});
        this.images.push({source:'assets/showcase/images/demo/galleria/galleria12.jpg', alt:'Description for Image 12', title:'Title 12'});
    }
```

ref: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/galleria

How to display images from File type or base64 strings? It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be straight forward. If you have your base64 images code you can push images using base.

```
  ngOnInit() {
        this.images = [];
        this.images.push({
            source:
                'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD, alt: 'Description for Image 2',
        title: 'Title 2', });
```

**Note: base64 is used in the image starting.** This is just a sample base64 encoding use your own files or upload your file to any of the cloud like Azure or AWS to get the link.

Hope it helps